# how to define multiple sftp connections?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I'm trying to use the outbound gateway to download files from multiple sftp servers, the number of sftp server is configured in properties(which means that i need to define the connection  dynamically),
 my application.properties:

```
sftp.host=host1,host2
sftp.user=user1,user2
sftp.pwd=pwd1,pwd2
```

current I use the java config as:

```
@Configuration
```

public class SFtpConfig {

```
static  Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SFtpConfig.class);

@Autowired
SftpServerProperties sftpServerProperties;

@Autowired
SftpClientProperties sftpClientProperties;

@Bean
public SessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory() {

 ...
}

@Bean(name = "myGateway")
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sftpChannel")
public MessageHandler handlerLs() {

 ...
}

@MessagingGateway
public interface DownloadGateway {
    @Gateway(requestChannel = "sftpChannel")
    List<File> start(String dir);
}

@Bean(name="sftpChannel")
public MessageChannel sftpChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

}
```

but this config is only for connect to one sftp server, so how can i define multiple sftp connections using the application.properties config?
 I mean dynamic number of sessionFactory/handler/gateway/channer (some of the bean has annotation, how to dynamic define such kind of bean?)

Answer (score 0):

You should consider to declare children `ApplicationContext` with the same content but different properties for `ConnectionFactories`:

```
/**
 * Set the parent of this application context.
 * <p>Note that the parent shouldn't be changed: It should only be set outside
 * a constructor if it isn't available when an object of this class is created,
 * for example in case of WebApplicationContext setup.
 * @param parent the parent context
 * @see org.springframework.web.context.ConfigurableWebApplicationContext
 */
void setParent(@Nullable ApplicationContext parent);
```

Comment: Hi @Artem, can u give more tips?  the number of sftp server is decided by  the properties file, I'v tried BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor but not success.